# How do I get grunt to watch and livereload with just one command - Gruntjs

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Here is my Gruntfile.js:
/*global module */

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  'use strict';

  // Load Grunt tasks declared in the package.json file
  require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

  grunt.initConfig({
    connect: {
      all: {
        options:{
          port: 9000,
          hostname: '0.0.0.0',
          base: 'app',
          keepalive: true,
          livereload: true
        }
      }
    },
    less: {
      development: {
        files: {
          'app/css/easier.css': 'app/less/easier.less'
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      less: {
        files: ['app/less/easier.less'],
        tasks: ['less']
      },
      scripts: {
        files: ['app/**/*.js'],
        options: {
          spawn: false,
          livereload: true
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server',[
    'connect',
    'watch'
  ]);
};
```

I run the `grunt server` command and my files get served up like they are supposed to.  In another console I run `grunt watch` and then if anything is changed it is automatically changed in the browser.  What will make this do all of this with just the command `grunt server`.  I thought by adding the task `watch` in the server task it would take care of this, but it is not working.  I try to enable `livereload` in Chrome with just the `watch` task and I get an alert that says `Could not connect to LiveReload server. Please make sure that LiveReload 2.3 (or later) or another compatible server is running.`  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `keepalive` to `false`, otherwise script will block and won't execute `watch` task.